# Как Извлечь текст, используя только requests и re

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, requests

```
import requests
import re

class News():
    def get_html():
        url = requests.get('https://lenta.ru/news/2022/02/06/mscmnsk/').text        
        text = re.findall(r'>([^<]+)</p>',url)#не правильно работает, не понимаю как исправить. 
        print(text)
        
News.get_html()
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: А зачем извлекать текст регулярками. Это довольно неблагодарное занятие. Что нибудь наверняка не учтете. Лучше пользоваться специализированными модулями для работы с html. И какой конкретно текст вы хотите извлечь.

Comment: Вот такая задача стоит, только статьи и заголовки к ним

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
import re

class News():

def get_html():
    
    HEADERS = {
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:87.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/87.0'}

    url = "https://lenta.ru/articles/2022/02/09/krg_tdj/"

    html = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, stream=True).text      
    
    text = re.sub(r'return+[^<]+return.................................................', '' ,html)

    text = re.sub(r'<[^/>]+', '' ,text)

    text = re.sub(r'</li+[^<].+?/>', '' ,text)

    text = re.sub(r'/javascript+[^<].+?/>', '' ,text)

    text = re.sub(r'</script+[^<].+?./>', '' ,text)

    text = re.sub(r'</script+[^<].+?/script>', '' ,text)

    text = re.sub(r'javascript+[^<].+?...+', '' ,text)

    text = re.sub(r'/script', '' ,text)

    text = re.sub(r'm.lenta.ru+[^<].+?.headline+', '' ,text)

    text = re.sub(r'."url"+[^<].+?.+"url"+[^<].+?', '' ,text)

    text = re.sub(r'https?://[^,\s]+,?', '' ,text)

    text = re.sub(r'[a-zA-Z/]', '' ,text)

    text = re.sub(r'<><><>><>><>>([\d\w\W]*)', '' ,text)

    text = re.sub(r'"}...844.([\d\w\W]*)>>><><>>><><><><>>', '' ,text)

    text = re.sub(r'\d{5,}', '' ,text)

    text = re.sub(r'[<>]+?', '' ,text)

    text = re.sub(r'..__620_.+?', '' ,text)

    text = re.sub(r'"":1280,"":720}]+?', '' ,text)

    text = re.sub(r'"":+?', '' ,text)

    text = re.sub(r'":+?', '' ,text)

    text = re.sub(r'1.._." Фото:+?', '' ,text)

    text = re.sub(r'"_"+?', '' ,text)

    text = re.sub(r'._________________...+?', '' ,text)

    text = re.sub(r'_.+?', '' ,text)

    text = re.sub(r'=+?', '' ,text)

    text = re.sub(r'Фото:.+?', '.' ,text)

    
    

    print(text)
    
    my_file = open("Cтатья.txt", "w+")
    my_file.write(text)
    my_file.close()
   
    
    

    
News.get_html()
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).